# Фильтрация типов данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

У меня есть файл **excel** в одном из столбце которого, по большей части, есть даты, но могут попадаться пустые строки или вообще текст. Мне необходимо отфильтровать только строки с датами, получить эту дату и сравнить ее с текущей датой, а также получить значения в связанных колонках этих строк. Я пытаюсь это сделать с помощью библиотек **Pandas** и **Openpyxl** но пока безрезультатно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда мне копать?

Comment: КАпать не надо никуда. КОпать надо в сторону перевода колонки в данные datetime с контролем ошибок. и подобные вопросы принято задавать с приведением своего кода и воспроизводимого примера данных.

Comment: *Мне необходимо отфильтровать только строки с датами* Ты сперва вообще определись, что будешь искать. Что в твоём понимании дата? обязательно чтобы формат ячейки был дата? или если тип ячейки строковый либо общий, но там значение, которое по формату совпадает с датой - то это тоже оно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерный сценарий:

- Пытаемся преобразовать колонку с предположительными датами в даты (можно при желании указать точный формат и другие параметры)
- Отфильтруем из получившегося `NA` и нереалистичные даты
- По получившейся маске берём наш исходный датафрейм

Параметры нужно подбирать в зависимости от ваших конкретных данных, но в целом примерно так.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['', 123, '2022-06-01', '2022-31-01', 'abc', '2022-03'], 
    'text': ['fssdf', 'rerre', 'frewffe', '43t4t4', 'rgerg', 'rgegre']
    })
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
mask = ~pd.isna(dates) & (dates > '2020-01-01')
df[mask]
```

| index | date | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-06-01 | frewffe |
| 5 | 2022-03 | rgegre |